# Negative counterpart for the word "rave" in the sense "favorable criticism"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

What is the one-word for a piece — art piece etc., maybe topic, subject — that has gained popularity through negative reviews or appraisals?

In other words, I am looking for a one-word noun or adjective that is the opposite of *rave* in the sense "favorable critism".

Comment: So first you need the opposite of a *rave review*, and then you need one that has gained positive notice as a result? Or can it be any notice whatsoever, even a negative one?  That is, it can not just famous but infamous?

Comment: Do you want a verb, noun, adjective? rave can be a noun, verb or adjective. A bit more context would be helpful.

Comment: "Raving" doesn't particular mean good or bad: it can usually mean excited talking.

Comment: I am looking for a noun or adjective of the  opposite one-word of RAVE in its sense of "favorable critism".

Comment: If the review is angry enough, you could use RAVE in the RAVING MAD sense...

Comment: It's not clear to me how these requests are connected. Something that has gained popularity through negative reviews is not something that I would name or describe with an antonym for “rave”. Can you share anything about the context of this need that would clarify how this is one thing?

Answer (score 29):

Well an antonym of "rave" would probably be "[pan](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pan?show=0&t=1396463549)".

> pan
>
> a harsh criticism

but perhaps you really want [notorious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/notorious),

> notorious
>
> well-known or famous especially for something bad

Comment: *Rant* also goes well with rave, although not in this context. +1 for *notorious.*

Comment: There are plenty of famous works that are referred to as having been "universally panned by critics".  My vote's here.

Comment: Infamous is an alternative to notorious, though **many** people either misuse or misunderstand the word (assuming it to mean simply famous).

Comment: @Doc I know, see my comment to the "infamy" answer below. Also, tchrist commented with "infamous" almost as soon as the question was posted.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Just trying to add detail for any reader's sake.  Not everyone reads comments to non-top-voted answers or even the question when browsing for their own sake.  Wasn't trying to imply that you were in any way unaware.

Answer (score 14):

I would go with **infamy** or its close cousin **infamous**.

> the state of being well known for some bad quality or deed.

Comment: the word for the " piece of art , maybe topic which has gained infamy" ? i feel the question could be paraphrased like this.... but it is not "the word"

Comment: @Argot It could be an `infamous` (or `notorious`) [piece](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piss_Christ).

Comment: this is i like , "close cousin"-- phrases like these cheer me up for some reason

Comment: I hope it's not because you have feelings for a cousin!

Answer (score 5):

There is a loan phrase from French: [succès de scandale](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/succes+de+scandale)

> *(Literary & Literary Critical Terms)* success of a play, book, etc, because of **notoriety** or its scandalous character
>
> [literally: success of scandal]

Comment: Seems similar in meaning (and intent) to "no such thing as bad publicity".

Answer (score 5):

[Scathing](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scathing) comes to mind as an adjective.

> bitterly severe, as a remark: *another restaurant has fallen victim to one of her scathing reviews*

Answer (score 3):

In BrE, *rubbish*, used as a verb, is a common word these days for the act of pouring scorn on a performance or an artistic work. *His book was rubbished by the critics. He rubbished her stand-up act*.

Comment: Though, in my experience, this is used only by tabloid newspapers.

Comment: The closest AmE might be _trashed_.

Answer (score 2):

[**Savage**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/savage) can be used as <strike>a noun</strike> an adjective or a verb for this purpose.

> to attack or criticize thoroughly or remorselessly; excoriate: *a play savaged by the critics.*
>
> *A savage review*

Comment: Post edit: there is no noun usage for savage in this sense; it is only a verb. All nounal usages for savage are for a type of person, none relating to a critic.

Answer (score 1):

### Something popular despite (and because of) widespread negative reception

“Notorious” is certainly a fine word for describing “a piece [. . .] that has gained popularity through negative reviews or appraisals”. I would also consider use of related terms like “guilty pleasure”, “kitch”, “(something) we love to hate”, or “so bad it's good” depending on the material and context. There's also the term “cult” to describe these sorts of pieces (esp. “cult classic”) or their followings.

If you have some space to explain yourself, you might consider coining “the [Regretsy](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/sites/regretsy) effect” which you could describe as the [curious phenomenon](http://www.etsy.com/teams/7722/discussions/discuss/8780876/) of explosive sales after a craft posting was criticized on the (now defunct) crafting ‘lowlight’ aggregator.

---

---

### Antonym for “rave”

### 1. Commentary on available options

**— — Verb — —**
“Pan” is used a lot, but I hear and read it much more often as a past-tense verb (not a noun), *e.g.:*

> The film was universally **panned** by critics.
>
> Ebert **panned** the film, decrying its sympathetic portrayal of a violent protagonist.

**— — Adjective — —**
If the word describes “review”, I think you're better off using “very critical” or “scathing”, *c.f.:*

> I read a **scathing** review of that movie.
> vs.
>   I read a **rave** review of that movie.

**— — Noun — —**
In that example, “review” could be taken out of the latter, and it would still make sense as a noun:

> I read a **rave** about that movie.

If your desire is a replacement for *that* usage, there isn’t a great one-word substitution. “Pan” is fine, but is less recognizable:

> I read a **pan** of that movie.

You might be better off just forcing the verb in that case:

> I read a **panning** of that movie.

There's also “(a) rant”, but that is difficult to recognize outside of collocations with “rave”.

---

### 2. My suggestions

It's not a single word, but as far as noun phrases go you might consider “hit piece” as in:

> “Did you read the A.V. Club review of *Howard Cantour.com?*”
> “Yeah, basically a **hit piece**.”

This has lots of problems itself, and is basically a metaphorical usage of the primary definition that has more to do with politics and is very similar to “smear campaign”. It also adds in a bit of negativity *about* the review, possibly conveying that the person using this term believed the review was overly harsh or resorted to *ad hominem.*

If you can trust context to communicate that you are talking about a review, you might just go fully metaphorical and say something like:

> Ebert's **evisceration** of *Transformers* comes as no surprise to anyone who knows his opinion of Michael Bay's characteristically baroque usage of CG.

There's also “takedown”, for which you probably won't find much dictionary backing (I couldn't) but might be useful in its modern usage (such as seen [here](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/valerie-stiversisakova/10-rules-of-writing-a-bad_b_4572229.html)).

Comment: Very nice answer... but rather then "takedown" I might use [put-down](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put-down).

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of alliteration, **ridiculed**

Comment: Alliteration with what?

Comment: As in "raved or ridiculed"